# How to declare Const pointer to const character array in C using []

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

The [const wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const_(computer_programming)#C_convention) states:

```
int *ptr; // *ptr is an int value
int const *ptrToConst; // *ptrToConst is a constant (int: integer value)
int * const constPtr; // constPtr is a constant (int *: integer pointer)
int const * const constPtrToConst; // constPtrToConst is a constant (pointer)
```

and

```
const int*       ptrToConst;     //identical to: int const *       ptrToConst,
const int* const constPtrToConst;//identical to: int const * const constPtrToConst
```

Great.

How does this apply if I use `[]` instead of `*` to declare an array? For example, how do I turn the following:

```
char s[] = "Hello";
```

into a "const pointer to const"?

Comment: Arrays are not pointers, though they decay to pointers in many contexts. You can't assign an entire array, so having a head-const array is pointless.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo So the question doesn't make sense then? Is the closest I can get to a immutable value `const char s[] = "Hello"` ?

Comment: @Ana you don't need more than that for an array, since the array name itself cannot be changed.  Only its contents can, and you've blocked that with the `const` declaration.

Comment: @TomKarzes: Sorry, my bad this time :-) But is is very well strongly related.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. First of all `s` is not a pointer, and because it's not a pointer you already can't change the array to "point" somewhere else.

So all you need is to make the contents of the array constant:

```
const char s[] = "Hello";
```

The above will declare `s` as an array of six constant `char` elements, and initialize the contents with the string `"Hello"`.

Comment: `const char s[] = "Hello";` will declare `s` as an array of 6 constant `char` elements.

Answer (score 1):

In C, when a qualifier is added to the array declaration then it qualifies the element type instead of array itself. C11 section: §6.7.3/9

> If the specification of an array type includes any type qualifiers, the element type is so- qualified, not the array type.[...]

So, it is not possible to declare *const array of const data type*.